# Beans, bacon, and chicken

Tags: chicken, beans, ingredient-selection, bacon

I am eating a mix of boiled bacon, broiled chicken, and boiled beans (+ salt & pepper). It tastes awkward. What can I add to improve this flavor within $5 to restaurant quality?

(I am not actually the one who came up with this concoction of madness)

Comment: Hello Evorlor. We don't do question of the type "What goes with X" or "what to add to X to taste better", because it has no valid answer. You can add any food or spice, and it's up to you whether you'll like it or not. Taste is not universal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you've made a typo, you should brown at least part of the bacon.  Browned bacon will add a great flavor that goes great with both beans and chicken.  Keep the bacon fat and just stir it in as well.  Just the beans and bacon is good.  If you're going for more of a baked beans type flavor, add some brown sugar and ketchup as well.

If the chicken is the star and this is supposed to be a whole meal, you need some kind of starch.  Given the chicken marinade and the beans, it sounds like it needs some rice or corn.  You could make a little rice pilaf, or put the rice in with the beans.  Creamed corn would also taste good with this, but the texture may not contrast with the beans enough.  Maybe a cornbread.

Comment: Sounds delicious. I should've specified, the chicken is the "hero" of the dish and it has some spice.

Comment: Are the beans like a salad on the side?  Is the bacon in with the beans?

Comment: Everything is solo atm

Comment: What kind of spices are on the chicken?

Comment: Lemon pepper, allegro hot & spicy marinade, (no s&p)

Comment: See updated answer